# What does "Advanced Functionality" mean?

Tags: red-orchestra-2

In Red Orchestra 2 and Rising Storm, when I join a Realism server, it says Advanced Functionality is enabled. What does that mean and do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is displayed when the server has had some of the advanced settings, [available through config files](http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=RO2_Dedicated_Server#Advanced_Configuration), manually changed.

Realism (well, all) servers frequently configure their settings to be more in line with the preferences of their hosts/players/owners - some might prefer some settings to be relaxed (or enforced), despite it otherwise being more realistic than 'action'.

Comment: Finally, an answer! Thanks a bunch! Enjoy the rep and RIP to my rank...